# The "Eloquent way": If no model found, drop where constraint

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a more "eloquent way" to code this behavior?

```
$this->template = Template::where('template_type_id', 1)
        ->where('locale', 'en')
        ->first() ?? Template::where('template_type_id', 1)
        ->first();
```

So I first want to check if there is a model with the `->where('locale', 'en')` condition, if not I want to drop this where condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `ORDER BY` clause to favour a template with a `locale` equal to `en`, and then select only the first result.

```
$template = Template::where('template_type_id', 1)
    ->orderByRaw("IF(locale = 'en', 1, 0) DESC")
    ->first();
```